# Google tag manager preview and debug showing event, but browser's debugger doesn't show any event

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

[click event implementation in gtm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0ARi.png)

[image: GTM Preview Pane]
[image: browser's debugger]

I tried to add click event using google tag manager. In tag manager's preview all events are coming up fine, but event not seen in browser's debugger network tab. As a result, no data is seen in google analytics real time report.

Please find screen shot attached

Answer (score 1):

You are filtering by the wrong string. The utm.gif was used by the ga.js tracking library.

Analytics.js, which is used by GTM, is based on the measurement protocol. So you should filter by requests where the request url starts with `collect` with google-analytics.com as domain (mostly this will be post requests where the payload is a string that starts with v=1 and then includes your tracking id, the client id and the actual tracking parameters).